# Magento 2 | Shipping Address gets set as Billing Address automatically

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address

whenever the user sets a new standard shipping address it automatically gets set as billing address too. 
The same in the opposite direction.

When he sets it for the first time both addresses get marked as standard shipping AND billing adresses.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: its because of you have only one address and magento required shipping and billing address so Magento set both default address.

Comment: To solve this issue , you will have to copy same address and set as a billing/shipping address.